# MSSQL Calculating Hours From Length Between TimeStamps

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am attempting to calculate hours worked from the database of a time clock. There are a few problems with the query i came up with that i cant figure out.

1) If a user doesnt clock out for the day it thinks the user worked until the clock in. If the user forgets to clock out the clock in should be thrown away from the query

2) The Query is VERY slow. Is there a better method i can use to speed it up?

```
WITH AUXILIERY_TBL AS (
SELECT [First Name],Checktime,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CheckTime ASC) AS Ordr
From Clock_Data 
LEFT JOIN Employees ON Employees.[ID Number] = Clock_Data.UserId 
    WHERE Employees.[First Name]='Hogen' AND Year(CheckTime) > YEAR(GetDate()) - 6 
    )
SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT 
         A.Ordr Number,a.[First Name],A.Checktime ct ,B.Checktime ct2,(DATEDIFF(MINUTE ,A.Checktime ,B.Checktime)/60) AS Hours
        FROM AUXILIERY_TBL AS A
        LEFT JOIN AUXILIERY_TBL AS B
               ON (A.Ordr=(B.Ordr-1))
   )c
WHERE c.Number % 2 <> 0
```

The Raw Data Looks Like This:

```
HOGEN                   2013-10-28 09:30:00
HOGEN                   2013-10-28 13:30:00
HOGEN                   2013-10-28 14:00:00
HOGEN                   2013-10-28 18:00:00
HOGEN                   2013-10-29 09:31:00
HOGEN                   2013-10-29 14:17:00
HOGEN                   2013-10-29 18:00:00
HOGEN                   2013-10-30 09:59:00
HOGEN                   2013-10-30 14:06:00
HOGEN                   2013-10-30 14:37:00
HOGEN                   2013-10-30 18:10:00
```

c.f. [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b4b9/6)

Comment: "sample data" should be provided "per source table", i.e. inserts for dbo.Clock_Data and for dbo.Employees, or you could setup a sqlfiddle perhaps.

Comment: Calculating (interpreting) hours worked can be extremely challenging.  Will you have to take into account Overtime, Doubletime, penalties for clocking in late, rounding forward/backward to the nearest 15 min interval, etc?  You've already run up into an abnormal situation for Question #1.  This might be the first of thousands.  I used to work for a company that wrote time & attendance software.  The "payroll rules" business logic (which would accommodate your scenario for Question #1) was extremely complex.  It was not written in tsql, either.  Not sure if this applies to you or if it helps.

Comment: By any change you can you upgrade Sql server to `Sql server 2012`

Comment: How to differentiate Clock In and Clock Out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually need is something like the `LAG` or `LEAD` analytic functions provided in SQLServer 2012+, which gets a column from the same select result N rows up or down, based on specified partitioning and ordering.

In my solution I'm looping through the Clock_Data table assuming that the times are check out time and then I simulate a `LAG` function with a correlated subquery to get the employee check in time based on each check out time. For sure not all times are check out, so I added in the subquery a `HAVING` condition to identify if the check in time been selected is an odd row in the times available before a check out in the same day. If yes, then return the time, if not return `null` so we can skip these rows after.

See the SQL and, please, try not to use column names with space character... at least, use an underscore character:

```
select 
  ep.[First Name],
  z.CheckIn,
  z.CheckTime as CheckOut,
  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, z.CheckIn, z.CheckTime)/60 AS Hours
from
(
  select 
    cd.*, 
    (
      -- simulating a LAG(CheckTime, 1, null) with this subquery
      select max(CheckTime)
      from Clock_Data
      where 1=1
        -- select only times from the same employee
        and UserID = cd.UserID
        -- select only times before the checkout time (cd.CheckTime)
        and CheckTime <  cd.CheckTime
        -- select only times from the same year/month/day
        and CheckTime >= convert(date, cd.CheckTime)
      group by UserID
      -- as we're selecting the max(CheckTime) before a check out time
      -- in the same day, we're selecting the immediatelly previous row/time
      -- but this subquery must select an odd number of rows
      -- to ensure the max(CheckTime) is a check in time
      -- since the check in always occurs first, before a check out
      -- if it's an even number of rows, null is returned
      having count(*) % 2 = 1
    ) as checkIn
  from Clock_Data cd
) z
inner join Employees ep on 1=1
  and ep.[ID Number] = z.UserID
  -- and ep.[First Name] = 'Hogen'
where 1=1
  and z.checkIn is not null
```